Jfrog artifactory helm upgrade to newer version
I have JFrog Artifactory version 7.16 installed via Helm in my Kubernetes cluster, and I want to upgrade it to version 7.90. What is the best way to do this?
The documentation only mentions a simple helm upgrade command, without much detail:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-version-7.x-to-7.x-helm-upgrade.
I considered scaling the current StatefulSet resources to 0 and installing the new Helm chart using the existing persistent volume claims for both PostgreSQL and Artifactory. However, I encountered an error stating that the existing volume was initialized by PostgreSQL 14, which isn't compatible with PostgreSQL 15, used in the new JFrog Helm chart.
I'm wondering if using the same PostgreSQL 14 image as the previous version might resolve the issue. However, I'm unsure if the existing data on the previous volume would be compatible with the new version of JFrog Artifactory.
